# Struts Tiles for php

Tags: php, struts, tiles

Hey does such a thing as Tiles in Struts exist in php (or some php-framework) ?

Comment: That's basically what PHP is :P

Comment: please explain what you mean ? Mchl

Comment: A little joke: PHP pretty much started as a templating system for HTML pages, and you can still use it like that. I don't know Tiles beyound what I've read in 'about' section of their site, so I'm not sure if there's a library that provides similar interfaces, there are however many templating libraries (standalone or within MVC frameworks) that I think could work well for you